# Simplifying Routing Web Api 2 With Optional/Default Parameters

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api-routing

We have the following routes we are adding with Web Api MapHttpRoute method:

```
api/{version}/{namespace}/{controller}/{id}/{action}
api/{namespace}/{controller}/{id}/{action}
api/{version}/{namespace}/{controller}/{id}
api/{namespace}/{controller}/{id}

api/{version}/{controller}/{id}/{action}
api/{controller}/{id}/{action}
api/{version}/{controller}/{id}
api/{controller}/{id}
```

Is there anyway to add these as one or does it have to be 8 separate routes in order to work?  we are using the namespace to mimick areas in web api and this is all working fine just would be great to reduce the number of routes.

I have tried setting RouteParameter.Optional and default values on the version, id and action.  Also we have a constraint on the version but still I cannot get this working without creating 8 routes.